# Add arrayNode inside ObjectNode - Jackson

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I want to have the following format:

```
   {
    "user1": {
        "courses": [
            "Math": {
                "grade": 1,
            },
            "English": {
                "grade": 1,
            }
        ]
    }
    "user2": {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Currently I have a LinkedHashMap, where eery user is a key, and in the values I have an object:

```
     Math: Int? = null
     English: Int? = null etc.

     result =  Map<String?, Courses>?: null
```

So I am iterating through the linkedhashmap, and for every property of the class, I need to add it to the "courses" array.
So far I have this:

```
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
    val objectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode()
    result?.forEach {
        val node = mapper.valueToTree<JsonNode>(it.value)
        val allFields: MutableIterator<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, JsonNode>>? = node.fields()
        objectNode.apply {
            set(
                it.key,
                objectMapper.createObjectNode().apply {
                    set(
                        "courses",
                        objectMapper.createArrayNode().apply {
                            while (allFields?.hasNext() == true) {
                                val nextNode = allFields.next()
                                set(nextNode.key,
                                    objectMapper.createObjectNode().apply {
                                        put("Grade", nextNode.value)
                                    }
                                ) as JsonNode
                            }
                        }) as ArrayNode

                }) as JsonNode
        }
    }
```

But I have an error being thrown that I cannot cast an objectNode to an ArrayNode.
How can I assign the courses within an array for every user?
The result variable has all users mapped to their courses.

I think the issue is when I am casting "as arrayNode" in the set of the ObjectNode.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should reconsider the whole approach here. You don't need to use a complex JSON API like this (which frankly is a pain to use). You can instead convert your data structure to the desired one in Kotlin, and then serialize it to JSON using whichever library you want

Comment: Also, what you provided as expected result is not valid JSON. You cannot have names in an array. `courses` should either be an object, or it should be an array but in that case the values in this array should be just objects (the name of the course should be part of those objects).